Strong Ditkin sets in the Fourier algebra
What is the definition of a Ditkin set (resp. a strong Ditkin set) for the Fourier algebra  $A(G)$ of a locally compact (not necessarily abelian) group  $G$?
More specifically, let $E$
be a closed subset of a locally compact group $G$. Let $I(E)$ denote the ideal of all $u\in A(G)$ vanishing on $E$, and $J(E)$ the closure (in the norm of $A(G)$) of the ideal of all $u\in A(G)$ whose support is compact and disjoint from $E$.
Usually, $E$
is defined to be Ditkin if every $u\in I(E)$ is contained in the closure of $uJ(E)$, so $u$ is approximable (in the norm of $A(G)$) by a sequence of the form $(uv_n)$ with $v_n\in J(E)$. The set $E$ is called strong Ditkin if the sequence $(v_n)$ can be chosen "uniformly for all $u\in I(E)$".
Here is the problem: in the strong Ditkin case, does it follow automatically that $\sup_n\|v_n\|_A$
is finite (where $\|\cdot\|_A$ is the norm of $A(G)$), or is this boundedness an extra requirement included in the definition of a strong Ditkin set?

I am not familiar with the relevant literature, but in the following 2015 paper of Kaniuth and Ülger

E. Kaniuth, A. Ülger, Strong Ditkin sets in the spectrum of a commutative Banach algebra and the Fourier algebra. Arch Math. (Basel) 105(2015), no.1, 67–77. MathReview | Zentralblatt

a precise definition is offered of "strong Ditkin set" for regular commutative Banach algebras, which they say is consistent with an older definition of Saeki in the particular case of Fourier algebras of LCA groups.
Definition 2.1 in that paper can be paraphrased as follows: given a regular semisimple CBA $A$ with Gelfand spectrum $\Delta(A)$, a closed subset $E\subseteq\Delta(A)$ is said to be a strong Ditkin set if there is a net $(v_\alpha)\in j(E)$ such that the corresponding net of multipliers $T_\alpha : I(E) \to I(E)$, $T_\alpha(f)=v_\alpha f$, satisfies $\sup_\alpha \lVert T_\alpha \rVert <\infty$ and $T_\alpha(f)\to f$ for all $f\in I(E)$.
So going back to your original question, it seems that one requires boundedness in the multiplier norm but not necessarily in the original norm. See also Lemma 2.3 and Theorem 4.1 in that paper for results that apply specifically to Fourier algebras.

Thank you very much Yemon! Do you know of an example (in the case of a sequence) of a strong Ditkin set where the $A(G)$-norms of the $v_n$'s have to blow up?.

... or, where the $M_{cb}A(G)$-norms of the $v_n$'s (norms as completely bounded - not just bounded- multipliers) have to blow up? - Thanks again!

@Aristides I haven't thought about this properly. If one allows $E$ to be empty, then the strong Ditkin condition is equivalent to the existence of an approximate identity for $A(G)$ that is bounded in the multiplier norm. This is formally weaker than weak amenability but I don't know of any examples where the two concepts differ. Nevertheless, in the case of your first question, any non-amenable weakly amenable $G$ would suffice for the case $E=\emptyset$.

In Example 4.2 of the Kaniuth-Ulger paper, they mention that by assembling some previous results from the literature, one can show that $A(G)$ has no multiplier-bounded approximate identity when $G={\bf Z}^2 \rtimes {\rm SL}_2({\bf Z})$; this is formally stronger than showing that $G$ is not weakly amenable.

My impression is that is still remains very unclear whether properties such as weak amenability and the Haagerup-Kraus AP are equivalent to the versions where one replaces the cb-multiplier norm with the multiplier norm. However, I have not kept up to date with developments during the last 6-8 years :-(
